# Prepend a div only on the form from where is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Hello I am making an application in nodejs. The Idea is a person can ask a question and someone else can reply. I already made the ask a question part but replying and showing the reply only from 1 question is troubling me this the code

```
function displayMsg(data){
            console.log(data);
            var name = data.name
            var msg = data.msg
            var id = data._id
    
            $messages.prepend("<div class='bubble'><strong>" + name + " says: " + "</strong>" + "<br/>" + msg + "<form id=" + id + " class='form-inline'><div class='form-group'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='reply" + id +"'></div><button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Reply</button></form><div id='replies" + id +"'></div></div>");       
        }
```

so this function displays a new question and I added in a form for the replies. I gave every form the id of the submitted question so every form has a unique id. So does the input field for the reply and the replies div where I want to prepend the replies.

now I was able to build a reply system but the replies are shown under every question.

I want the replies only shown under the question they reply to

You can see my complete javascript(jquery) code in this fiddle. It obviously won't work since it's Jade and node + socketio https://jsfiddle.net/bvLnLkwL/3/

Comment: Make a fiddle please.

Comment: wrap the value of the form's id attribute in quotes

Comment: also you will probably want to put the popup somewhere else, if $messages.prepend() is putting it in the wrong place

Comment: it's a bit hard to make a fiddle since it's a node project and there is a bunch of socketio involved

Comment: I think that the problem is that I can only grab the replies form inside the function I need to be able to grab it outside the function

Comment: I changed it up a bit but I simply don't know wht the replies come under all the forms instead only under the form from where s submitted. I always have this problem I was building something in php exactly the same problem couldn't fix it and never touched the project again. Please help me I am desperate. https://jsfiddle.net/4w12r23b/

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in the specific technologies you're using, but on first glance I'd say that the problem is that your listeners are all listening for the same, global `new reply` event, without identifying if the reply is relevant to their specific question id.

Unless this is something SocketIO handles itself, you probably want to either create different reply channels to listen to for each form, or check the question id in your listener.

For example, send the ID with the data:

```
socket.on('new_reply', function(data){
    if(data.question === id) {
        $repliesDiv.prepend("<div id='areply'>"+data.reply+"</div>");
        $('#areply').addClass("fadeInTop");
    }
});
```

Or make unique 'channels', like this:

```
socket.on('new_reply.' + id, function(data){
    $repliesDiv.prepend("<div id='areply'>"+data.reply+"</div>");
    $('#areply').addClass("fadeInTop");
});
```

I'm not sure if / how this last one would impact performance though.

Comment: I'm quite new to SocketIO so I don't know exactly how it all works. But your reasoning makes sense, I only have no idea how to apply it.

Comment: @user1439495 Send the question id with the response data, so you can check the ids in your listener, for example. Or listen to events with the id included in the name, so you know all replies will be about that question.

Comment: Im not sure how to do this

Comment: @user1439495 See the updated answer, it shows some basic code. Just make sure to add the ID on the reply sending side in a similar manner and it should work. (I can't give you examples on that, because I don't know what your code looks like on that side).

Comment: Okay I will try some stuff out and let you know if it works or not :) thanks a lot!

Comment: I forgot to mention I changed it up I don't work with the id anymore. I now work with a counter that I add +1 to everytime a new question is posted. So the form id looks like this id='form1' you can see the client side code here http://pastie.org/10078222 and the this is the server side code http://pastie.org/10078228

Comment: I fixed it that the replies are shown only under the right question but the reply is shown equal amount of times as there are questions so if there are 2 questions and you reply on question 1 it is shown under question1(this is good) but the answer is shown 2 times since there are 3 questions http://pastie.org/10078308

Comment: @user1439495 This should work better: http://pastie.org/10078325. Compare the received ID to the scoped ID, and prepend to the scoped div.